# Finding US marine ancestor without knowing birthdate?

Tags: united-states, germany, military-records, world-war-2, mississippi

I am trying to track down my US grandad / his family but keep hitting brick walls without his date of birth. I am English but my mum was born in Germany in 1949 to a German National mum and a US Marine.

From the following information, do you think it is possible to track the US marine and if so what route would you recommend?

Searching German or US records?

From - Mississippi USA (possibly Tupelo)
Stationed in - Bremerhaven, Germany 1948
Year of birth - probably between 1923 and 1930
Photo - shows him as (possibly) a staff sergeant, and posed with a Jeep. Registration C-16498 with perhaps a motor pool connection
Family - 9 siblings.

His family wrote to say that he was MIA when my gran was pregnant with my mum but we are unsure if that was the case.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Unfortunately, your grandad appears to have been born much less than the 100 years ago that triggers our Privacy Policy which you can view in the [help/on-topic] , and so I will need to redact his name from your post.

Answer (score 2):

Contact Jennifer Holik; she knows WWII era and Korean War era records for deceased servicemen better than anyone. She did four presentations at the giant national genealogy conference RootsTech this past February; one of them might be available online on their website or YouTube channel for free viewing. Here's her website: http://wwiiresearchandwritingcenter.com/